# Understanding a proof that $\operatorname{Aut(}S_3) \simeq S_3$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, automorphism-group

I am trying to understand a proof that $S_3$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}(S_3)$ located on page 2 of this link:
[http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/~hchu/Algebra/Jacobson%5B19%5D.pdf](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchu/Algebra/Jacobson%5B19%5D.pdf)

I'm going to rewrite the proof in my own words and pause at the steps that I can't follow.

> We have
> $$S_3 = \{e, a = (123), a^2 = (132), b = (12), ab = (123)\},$$
> so, e.g., $S_3 = \langle (123), (12) \rangle$. It follows then that $ba = a^2 b$, which implies that
> \begin{align*}
> (a^m b^n)(a^p b^q) = a^{m+(n+1)p} b^{n+q},
> \end{align*}
> where $m,p \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $n,q \in \{0,1\}$.

My first point of confusion is trying to verify this. One possibility is running over cases, but there must be an easier way. First, the claim seems to be that because $S_3$ is generated by $a$ and $b$, I can write any element $x \in S_3$ as $x = a^m b^n$ where $m \in \{0,1,2\}$ (since the order of $a$ is $3$) and $n \in \{0,1\}$ (since $b$ has order $2$). The problem then becomes that I don't know how to introduce $ba = a^2 b$ since I don't know if I have two factors of $a$ to work with. I assume this boils down to an associativity argument, but I'm struggling to see how to do it.

> Given any automorphism $\phi$ acting on $x \in G$, $\phi(x)$ has the same order as $x$. Then $\phi(a) = a^i$ and $\phi(b) = a^j b$ where $i = 1,2$ and $j = 0,1,2$.

I understand the first sentence but not what follows. $a$ has order $3$, but upon mapping it to $a^I$, it no longer has order $3$; similarly for mapping $b$, an element of order $2$, to $a^j b$. Am I missing something here?

The remainder of the proof follows from these facts, so I think if I could understand these steps, I could probably make sense of the rest.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of the expression
$$S_3 = \{e, a = (123), a^2 = (132), b = (12), ab = (123)\}.$$
What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: You can do a simple proof by noting that $|\operatorname{Aut}(S_3)|\le 6$ and all groups of order less than 5 are abelian. Then construct two maps that don't commute.

Comment: As for the verification of the equation $ba=a^2b$: You know what $a$ and $b$ are, right? Remember $a=(123)$ and $b=(12)$. You know how to multiply permutations, right? So, simply compute the left and right hand sides of the equation $ba=a^2b$ and compare...

Comment: I know how to verify $ba = a^2 b$, but I don't know how to verify the generalization $(a^m b^n)(a^p b^q)$ that follows from it.

Comment: @Servaes: I called the identity permutation $e$, $a = (123)$, $b = (12)$, and then wrote the remaining elements of the permutation group in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: When you calculate the product $(a^mb^n)(a^pb^q)$ the only part you need to worry about is the $b^na^p$ in the middle. The rest are already where you want them ($a$s on the left, $b$s on the right). If $n=0$ then there is no $b^n$ and you are done. When $n=1$ you need to bring $b^n=b$ to the right of $a^p$. To do that you use the rule $ba=a^2b$ as many times as needed. There are $p$ factors $a$ to the right of $b$, and each and every one of them becomes $a^2$. So irrespective of whether $n=0$ or $n=1$ the rule $b^na^p=a^{(n+1)p}b^n$ holds. Done.

Comment: You give a set that has five elements; that cannot be $S_3$, which has six elements, so you are missing something. Also, you claim that $ab=(123)$, that is, that $ab=a$. That's false, since $b\neq e$. Depending on how you multiply your permutations (composing right-to-left or left-to-right), $ab$ should equal either $(13)$, or $(23)$, respectively.